# Can Android Apps Ask for Microphone Permission after Application Start

Tags: android, permissions

We're recreating our native iOS app in native Android, and I was told that any permissions we require inside the app must be asked upon starting the application. Is this true? I ask because we have certain activities inside the app that require mic access to use, but I'm concerned that if a user were prompted upon the application start they would (understandably) decline the permission and then be unable to use our app. Any clarity here would be very helpful.

Comment: This is the first Google result when searching "android permissions". https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to ask for runtime permissions at the app startup. This was only true for older android versions up to android 5.1 (API level 21).

Starting with android 6.0 (API level 23) "Dangerous permissions" or "[Runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#runtime)" need to be granted by the user at runtime. The best practice is to "Ask for permissions in context, when the user starts to interact with the feature that requires it" ([source](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#principles)).